# Bokeh Histogram of Roulette Game not showing up, am I missing something?

Tags: python, histogram, bokeh

**So I'm making a roulette game, here are the guidelines:**

Roulette is a casino game that involves a steel ball spinner around a wheel. There are 38 slots where the ball might drop. 18 of those slots are colored red, another 18 are colored black and 2 are colored green. When you bet on either red or black and win, you get back twice the amount of your original bet. For example, if you bet $1, you would get an extra $1 for winning, but you would lose that original $1 if you lost.

Simulate 200 people playing roulette, each betting $1 on red 100 times.
Create a line chart and an appropriate histogram that describes these results.
Make sure to label your line chart and histogram.

---

So I believe my code for the game is right, but the histogram is showing up as a blank graph without anything on it.
Am I missing something? Is there something else I need to add or incorporate?

---

**Here's what I have written for this.**

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

def roulette(x):
    results = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, x):
        roll = random.randint(1, 38)
        if roll <= 18:
            count += 1
            results.append(count/i)
        else:
            count -= 1
            results.append(count/i)
   
    return results

def listf(x):
    for i in range(x):
        return(roulette(100)[-1])

roulette_list = listf(200)

hist = np.histogram(roulette_list, bins = 10, range = (0, 200))

yval = hist[0]
xval = hist[1]

xbarwidth = xval[1] - xval[0]

xval = xval + xbarwidth/2
xval = xval[0:-1]

print(xval)

f = figure()
for x, y in zip(xval, yval):
    f.vbar(x, xbarwidth, y, line_color = "white")

show(f)
```

Comment: Please edit your post to use code formatting.

Comment: If you print your variable `yval` you see, all values are 0. This is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your bokeh code works perfectly, here you can see a minimal example with self defined `xval` and `yval`.

```
xval = [1,2,3,4]
yval = [1,2,3,4]
xbarwidth = 1
f = figure()
for x, y in zip(xval, yval):
    f.vbar(x, xbarwidth, y, line_color = "white")
show(f)
```

[image: simple bar plot]

You have to ckeck your implementation for the `roulette()` and `listf`. If you call

```
roulette_list = listf(200)
```

this returns only one value right now and than `np.histogram` doesn't work as intended.

**Edit**
My you can substitute your  call `roulette_list = listf(200)` function with `roulette_list =`[`np.random.randint(0, 38, size=200, dtype=int)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html). If you do so for a test, you will see some output in your figure.